# Get closest (source or target) of an edge from a point in postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a Postgres custom function that uses pgr_dijkstra to generate a route working. It works be passing the lat/lon of the start and destination points. I then find the closest segment vertice to that lat/lon point and use that in the pgr_dijkstra call.

`snippit:
EXECUTE 'SELECT id::integer FROM trail_split_segs_vertices_pgr 
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText(''POINT(' 
            || x1 || ' ' || y1 || ')'',4326) LIMIT 1' INTO rec;
    source := rec.id;`

The problem is even though I may be moused over a specific segment, the closest vertex might belong to a different segment, since its doing the lookup based on distance.

[image: the red point is the one I want, but I get the purple one since its closer]

(the red point is the one I want, but I get the purple one since its closer)

I tried creating a different function to instead find the closest edge to the users lat/lon points rather than the closest vertex. But I have to choose if i'm going to use that edge's source or target.

`snippit
SELECT 
  id, source, target, geom, ST_Distance(
    geom, ST_GeometryFromText(
      'POINT(-123.036073 49.357152)', 4326
    )
  ) AS dist 
FROM
  trail_split_segs 
WHERE geom && ST_SetSRID(
    'BOX3D(-123.036083 49.357142, -123.036063 49.357162)'::box3d, 4326
  ) 
ORDER BY dist 
LIMIT 1`

The box created by this is very small, so pretty much will always select the correct edge, because I have the users mouse snap to the edges in the web interface.

What I want to do is select the edge source or target that is closest to the lat/lon point where the id of the edge has to be the same.

**UPDATE**
Zia's response below helped set me on the right track, I modified his query.

`WITH 
point AS 
    (SELECT st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-123.0568528175354, 49.36230206100319), 4326) AS point),
line AS 
    (SELECT 
    geom AS line_geom 
    FROM
    trail_split_segs, point
    WHERE st_dwithin(geom, point, 0.00012)
    ORDER BY geom <-> point
    LIMIT 1)
SELECT 
id, ST_AsText(the_geom) AS point_geom 
FROM
trail_split_segs_vertices_pgr, line, point 
WHERE st_dwithin(the_geom, line_geom, 0.00001) 
ORDER BY the_geom <-> point
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: How is the vertex pointed to by the red arrow supposed to be identified. Is there another intersection there, your image doesn't show?

Comment: It is the "source" id of that edge. Each edge/segment has a source & target ID/node.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to set the `BOX3D`, instead use the following approach. But keep in mind that the `0.00012` is a bit crucial, you have to select it carefully. Don't insert `0` instead as I have noticed some abnormal behavior in the past. Plus, if your CRS is in ESPG:3857 then you have to defined this buffer value not in degrees but meters.

```
with line as
(select geom as line_geom from trail_split_segs order by
geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-123.036073 49.357152), 4326) limit 1)
select id, the_geom as point_geom from trail_split_segs_vertices_pgr, line
where st_dwithin(the_geom, line_geom, 0.00012) 
order by the_geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-123.036073 49.357152), 4326) limit 1;
```

Comment: this still gives the same result as above, it doesn't restrict to the edge, so the purple point is selected. BUT this helped set me on the right path, thank you!

Comment: It's strange why the result is still the same. Anyways, your welcome.